# Query with large WHERE clause causes timeout exception in EF6 with npgsql

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, npgsql

I have a query that looks something like this:

```
private static IQueryable<MultiframeModule> WhereAllFramesProperties(this IQueryable<MultiframeModule> query, ICollection<Frame> frames)
{
    return frames.Aggregate(query, (q, frame) =>
    {
        return q.Where(p => p.Frames.Any(i => i.FrameData.ShaHash == frame.FrameData.ShaHash));
    });
}
```

`MultiframeModule` and `Frame` have an many-to-many relation.

With that query I want to find a `MultiframeModule` that contains all frames inside the `frames` collection I sent as a parameter, for that I check the `ShaHash` parameter.

If `frames` contains 2 frames, then the generated SQL would be something like that:

```
SELECT
   "Extent1"."MultiframeModuleId",
   "Extent1"."FrameIncrementPointer",
   "Extent1"."PageNumberVector" 
FROM
   "public"."MultiframeModule" AS "Extent1" 
WHERE
   EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT
         1 AS "C1" 
      FROM
         "public"."Frame" AS "Extent2" 
         INNER JOIN
            "public"."FrameData" AS "Extent3" 
            ON "Extent2"."FrameData_FrameDataId" = "Extent3"."FrameDataId" 
      WHERE
         "Extent1"."MultiframeModuleId" = "Extent2"."MultiframeModule_MultiframeModuleId" 
         AND "Extent3"."ShaHash" = @p__linq__0
   )
   AND EXISTS 
   (
      SELECT
         1 AS "C1" 
      FROM
         "public"."Frame" AS "Extent4" 
         INNER JOIN
            "public"."FrameData" AS "Extent5" 
            ON "Extent4"."FrameData_FrameDataId" = "Extent5"."FrameDataId" 
      WHERE
         "Extent1"."MultiframeModuleId" = "Extent4"."MultiframeModule_MultiframeModuleId" 
         AND "Extent5"."ShaHash" = @p__linq__1
   )
   LIMIT 2

-- p__linq__0: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)

-- p__linq__1: '0' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
```

But, if I have more frames, say 200 for example, then the call would throw an exception:

```
Unable to read data from the transport connection: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
```

With stacktrace:

```
   at Npgsql.ReadBuffer.<Ensure>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<DoReadMessage>d__157.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>d__156.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadExpecting>d__163`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.<NextResult>d__32.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<Execute>d__71.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.<ExecuteDbDataReader>d__92.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ValueTaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

So, is there some obvious reason why my query is failing? And how can I improve it to be able to do the query successfully?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the problem is caused by the too many subqueries in the generated SQL query.

In my test environment, SqlServer (LocalDB) simply refuses to execute the generated query with the reason as *being too complex*. PostgreSQL was able to execute it  (after setting the `CommandTimeout` to 0) in ~4min.

The solution is to find equivalent construct which does not generate many subqueries. What I usually use in such case in the *counting the distinct matches and comparing it to the criteria count* approach.

It can be implemented in two ways.

(1) This is applicable only for conditions of type `property == valueN`. In such case, counting the distinct matches can be done like this (in pseudo code):

```
obj.Collection
   .Select(elem => elem.Property)
   .Distinct()
   .Count(value => values.Contains(values))
```

Applying it to your sample:

```
private static IQueryable<MultiframeModule> WhereAllFramesProperties(this IQueryable<MultiframeModule> query, ICollection<Frame> frames)
{
    var values = frames.Select(e => e.FrameData.ShaHash);
    var count = frames.Count();
    return query.Where(p => p.Frames.Select(e => e.FrameData.ShaHash)
        .Distinct().Count(v => values.Contains(v)) == count);
}
```

(2) This is applicable for any type of condition. In this case the match is identified by its index, which requires building dynamically a selector expression like this:

```
Condition0 ? 0 : Condition1 ? 1 : ... ConditionN-1 ? N - 1 : -1
```

and the distinct match count would be

```
obj.Collection
   .Select(selector)
   .Distinct()
   .Count(i => i >= 0)
```

Applying it to your sample:

```
private static IQueryable<MultiframeModule> WhereAllFramesProperties(this IQueryable<MultiframeModule> query, ICollection<Frame> frames)
{
    var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(MultiframeModuleFrame), "e");
    var body = frames.Select((frame, index) =>
    {
        Expression<Func<Frame, bool>> predicate = e => e.FrameData.ShaHash == frame.FrameData.ShaHash;
        return new
        {
            Condition = predicate.Body.ReplaceParameter(predicate.Parameters[0], parameter),
            Value = Expression.Constant(index)
        };
    })
    .Reverse()
    .Aggregate((Expression)Expression.Constant(-1), (next, item) =>
        Expression.Condition(item.Condition, item.Value, next));
    var selector = Expression.Lambda<Func<Frame, int>>(body, parameter);
    var count = frames.Count();
    return query.Where(p => p.Frames.AsQueryable().Select(selector)
        .Distinct().Count(i => i >= 0) == count);
}
```

where the `ReplaceParameter` is the following custom extension method:

```
public static partial class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

The generated SQL contains a huge `CASE WHEN` expression (unfortunately doubled in the `WHERE` clause), but a *single* subquery, and is accepted and successfully executed in both SqlServer and PostgreSQL (in the later case in less ~2 sec under the same condition as the original test - 1K records in both tables, 1M links, 200 conditions).

Comment: Thanks for the amazing answer! I was just wondering, is it possible to change the query to only match if the Frame collection is exact the same? As now, if I have a MultiframeModule A with 2 frames, and I query for a MultiframeModule B with 1 frame (which is one of the 2 frames in the A multiframeModule) the query will return A, with its 2 frames.

Comment: You are welcome:) Regarding your question, what if you add `p => p.Frames.Count() == count && ....` to the query criteria?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable timeouts by passing `Command Timeout=0` in the connection string, as with a default of 30 seconds your queries are probably running for too long and you need to optimize things.

Comment: I did that, but even so, I left the query running for like 15 ~ 20 minutes and it didn't finish even when the database was simply empty.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `any` clause inside of a `where`, maybe you would try to optimize it

```
return frames.Aggregate(query, (q, frame) =>
        {
            return q.Frames.Any(i => i.FrameData.ShaHash == frame.FrameData.ShaHash));
        });
```